# XSLT: how to combine 2 xml files to one table

Tags: html, xml, database, xslt, html-table

I need to create HTML from XSLT file. The problem is that I don't know how to manage with 2 XMLs. I tried something like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:b="http://www.demo.com" xmlns:a="http://www.demo.com/author" 
xmlns:p="http://www.demo.com/person" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
etc ... 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">

    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:variable name="bookFile" select="document('file:///C:/Users/Kacper Makuch/Desktop/library/book.xml')"></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="authorFile" select="document('file:///C:/Users/Kacper Makuch/Desktop/library/author.xml')"></xsl:variable>

            <h1>Book Collection</h1>

            <table border="4">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                </tr>

                <xsl:for-each select="$bookFile//b:book">
                <xsl:variable name="idBook" select="@id"></xsl:variable>
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="$idBook"/></td>
                    <!--<td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>-->
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of 
select="$authorFile//a:author[bookId=$idBook]/p:lastname"/></td>
                </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>         
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the output there are correctly iterated books from xml with correct IDs, but without their names and `p:lastname`s of authors.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution where it works like this:

`<xsl:variable name="IdToAdd" select="document('D:/EXPORT/FOLDER/File.xml')/Satz/@id"></xsl:variable>`

Have you tried without file:/// and without whitespaces?

Comment: variables effectively shortened my code, thank you. `file:///` works fine

Answer (score 0):

I've managed this problem. The problem was with prefixes, namely in my xml input 
files 
I've got defined default namespace (with no prefix) and namespace with prefix 
with 
the same URI. It's proper, but in XSLT, XPath expression must have prefix. I've 
omitted 
prefix and that's why my output was empty. Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:b="http://www.demo.com" xmlns:a="http://www.demo.com/author" 
xmlns:p="http://www.demo.com/person" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" etc
<xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">

    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:variable name="bookFile" select="document('file:///C:/Users/Kacper 
Makuch/Desktop/library/book.xml')"></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="authorFile" select="document('file:///C:/Users/Kacper 
Makuch/Desktop/library/author.xml')"></xsl:variable>

            <h1>Book Collection</h1>

            <table border="4">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                </tr>

                <xsl:for-each select="$bookFile//b:book">
                <xsl:variable name="idBook" select="@id"></xsl:variable>
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="$idBook"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="b:name"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of 
select="concat($authorFile//a:author[a:bookId=$idBook]/p:firstname, ' ', 
$authorFile//a:author[a:bookId=$idBook]/p:lastname)"/></td>
                </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>         
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```